# Reinitialize jsf custom component after ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a custom component based on JavaScript to initialize it after DOM complete.
but when I update the component by an Ajax call, it will be updated but it never initialized..

I read some code of primeFaces and omniFaces but it seems not very simple to do that.

What is the best way to call the JavaScript code to reinitialize the component after every Ajax update.

**edit:**

Suppose i want to transform a jQuery Plugin (like select2) to jsf custom component, and i want to call the jQuery method `$('#myComponentId').select2()` after every ajax update

this is what i need

thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be best to share some code, such as what you have tried so far.

Comment: What are you using to start your ajax (button, ...) ? Which version of JSF and PrimeFaces are you using? Are you interested to use another component library or not?

Comment: I'm building a jar library(web fragment project) in JSF2.2 without any external component library, and I create a class extend from `javax.faces.render.Renderer` to build the component.
So what is the code inside this class (I supposed this is the correct place ) to do my job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by rendering a JavaScript after the component to reinitialize it..

**Exmaple:**

```
<div id="myComponent" name="myComponent">
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#myComponent").select2();
   </script>
</div>
```

and when the component updated after an Ajax call, the JavaScript will execute automatically